# Scikit learn Decision Tree not deterministic

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am doing recursive feature elimination and cross-validated selection (RFECV) in order to get the best number of features. As I will be comparing different hyper-parameters and methods in dealing with unbalanced data at a later stage I would like the best features to be deterministic. Therefore I have used a decision tree. However, every time I run the code below I get a different no. of best features. I have used a constant random state throughout and cannot understand why the results differ between runs?

```
RANDOM_ST = 123

def featureSelection(train, train_labels, test, test_labels):

    # Use kNN to illustrate effectiveness of feature selection. 
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier()

    # train the classifier
    clf = clf.fit(train, train_labels['gname_code'])

    # predict the class for unseen examples
    preds = clf.predict(test)

    # initial accuracy
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(preds, test_labels['gname_code'])
    print('Initial Result', score)

    # Decision tree for feature selection
    # RF is probably a better way to do feature selection but I want it to be deterministic for 
    # comparing unblanaced methods later. So use decTree instead
    #estimator = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=RANDOM_ST)
    estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_ST)

    # Custom cv so I can seed with random state => results are comparable between different options later
    rskv = model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=5, random_state=RANDOM_ST)

    # Greedy Feature Selection
    rfecv= RFECV(estimator, cv=rskv, n_jobs=-1)
    rfecv.fit(train, train_labels['gname_code'])

    # optimal number of features
    print('Optimal no. of features is: ', rfecv.n_features_)

    # drop the un-informative features
    train = train.iloc[:, rfecv.support_]
    test = test.iloc[:, rfecv.support_]

    # test again now
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(train, train_labels['gname_code'])
    preds = clf.predict(test)
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(preds, test_labels['gname_code'])
    print ('Result after feature selection: ', score)


    return train, train_labels, test, test_labels
```

Comment: not sure if it is helping, but how about at `random_state`to clf also?

Comment: @PV8 it is the rfecv that I want to be deterministic not the classification. Adding a random state to clf has no impact on feature selection.